# Trigger a Jenkins job after commit on different repository

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, commit

I have a pipeline job on Jenkins which run tests and it's linked to repository 'A', I want to trigger this job once in repository 'B' a commit done.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generic-webhook-trigger-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin) and [git](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)

- Set webhook on Repository B using generic-webhook-trigger-plugin
- Set trigger on commit on Repository B
- Checkout Branch on Repository A using Git
- Run test in Repository A